# How to improve peformance of simple sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to improve peformance of simple sql query
consider below fields in table

```
id, name, empId, address, contact, joiningDate, designation, location

select * from tblEmployee where location = "Amsterdam"
```

Currently it is taking 3seconds, how to reduced it.

Please suggest all possible solution or way for improve query performance.

Comment: Post the query execution plan, along with all the indexes for the table

Comment: How big is the table? Is the `location` field indexed? You haven't provided any information and the only answer one can give is 'use an index'

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh MS SQL Server

Comment: @ChicksPatel don't use irrelevant tags then, unless you *want* to get downvoted. Post the table schema *including* indexes and the *execution plan*. How many rows are there anyway? How many rows match the query? 3 seconds that returns 100K rows from a 100M row table isn't that bad.

Comment: @ChicksPatel if you have a lot of data the disk and network speed also paly a role. RAM **always** plays a role

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, use single quotes for string literals. I.e. `"Amsterdam"` is a column having the name Amsterdam, `'Amsterdam'` is a string with the value Amsterdam.

Answer (score 1):

You could create index on `location` column.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_emp ON tblEmployee(location);
-- NONCLUSTERRED is default

-- please note that I've changed " to '
select * from tblEmployee where location = 'Amsterdam';
```

Comment: might not be used; depends on row count and selectivity, since it's not covering

Comment: 1) which index? 2) primary or clustered? 3) How to create it?

Comment: @ChicksPatel that's answered in the documentation and all tutorials. This question is far too vague to begin with.

Comment: 3d question is already answered: the statement posted by @lad2025 creates the index, you only need to run it. 1st question already answered too: an index called `ix_emp` (well the name doesnt actually matter, you could call it `myredfishnameisbryan`, sql server doesnt care about that) and it covers the `location` column.